# Github Action: actions/setup-node@v1 is not working

Tags: node.js, github-api, github-actions

in my GitHub action YAML file, the process hangs when `actions/setup-node@v1` is executed.
same YAML file works yesterday, but why it hangs now?

```yaml
name: "Github Actions Test"
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    env:
      PRISMA_ENDPOINT: ${{secrets.PRISMA_ENDPOINT}}
      PRISMA_SECRET: ${{secrets.PRISMA_SECRET}}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: "Install Node"
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '12.x'
      - name: "Install global packages"
        run: npm install -g yarn prisma-cli
      - name: "Run docker Container"
        run: docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build -d
      - name: "Install deps"
        run: yarn install
      - name: "prisma deploy"
        run: yarn deploy:backend
      - name: "Build app"
        run: yarn build:backend
      - name: "Seed Backend"
        run: yarn seed:backend
      - name: "Start backend"
        run: yarn start:backend
```

Comment: any error message?

Comment: Could you try restarting the GitHub Actions workflow?

Comment: Is this the error you're facing? https://github.com/actions/setup-node/issues/133